# What is $\operatorname{Var}[aX+bY+c]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I know that $\operatorname{Var}[aX+bY]=\operatorname{Cov}[aX+bY,aX+bY]=a^2\operatorname{Var}[X]+2ab\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]+b^2\operatorname{Var}[Y]$ (by expanding $(ax+by)(ax+by)$ and letting $\operatorname{Var}[X]=x^2$-terms, $\operatorname{Var}[Y]=y^2$-terms and $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]=xy$-terms).

But what happens when we've got an $x$-term or a $y-$term on its own?

e.g. say we want $\operatorname{Var}[X+Y+1]$.

Then we have $(x+y+1)^2=x^2+2xy+2x+y^2+2y+1$, so:
$$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y+1]=\operatorname{Var}[X]+2\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]+2?+\operatorname{Var}[Y]+2?+1.
$$ Could someone fill in the blanks?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should consider $\text{cov} (aX, Z)$ where $Z = bY+c$

Comment: @Alex Doing this, though, we get: $Cov(aX,Z)=Cov(aX,bY+c)=abCov(X,Y)+ac?$ (again, we have an $x$ term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the variance, getting it through the covariance formula the way you're doing is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  You just observe:  $${\rm Var}[X + Y + 1] = {\rm Var}[X + Y],$$ because ${\rm Var}[X + c] = {\rm Var}[X]$ for any constant $c$.  **Then** you can use the covariance formula.

Comment: So, when dealing with variances of a linear combination of random variables (including constants), we can effectively ignore the constants, so $Var[aX+bY+c]=Var[aX+bY]$?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, this applies to other functions of random variables; e.g., if $W = f(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ where $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are not necessarily IID random variables, then we still have ${\rm Var}[W + c] = {\rm Var}[W]$.  The case you have here is simply $f(X,Y) = aX + bY$, but it would also be true if, for example, $f(X,Y) = XY$.

Comment: this amounts to setting $X+Y=Z$, so $\text{Var}[X+Y+1] = \text{Var}[Z+1]=\text{Var}Z = \text{Var}X + \text{Var}Y+2 \text{Cov}(X,Y)$

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it except that 
$$
\text{Cov}(aX, bY+c) = \text{Cov}(aX, bY)+\text{Cov}(aX,c) = ab \text{Cov}(X,Y) +0
$$
because covariance of a random variable with a constant is $0$.

http://www.kaspercpa.com/statisticalreview.htm

Comment: So am I right in thinking that the $x$-terms and the $y$-terms (on their own) become 0?

Comment: define 'on their own'

Comment: As in, if we expand $(ax+by+c)^2$, any $x$-terms or $y-terms$.

Comment: I don't understand the connection to the binomial expansion with $n=2$. The main point is that the covariance of a random variable and a constant (degenerate rv) is always $0$.

Comment: My professor told us (as an intuitive thing more than anything), that, if we want to find $Cov(aX+bY,cX+dY)$, we should expand $(ax+by)(cx+dy)$, and the $x^2$-terms become $Var[X],$ the $y^2$-terms become $Var[Y]$ and the $xy$-terms become $Cov[X,Y]$, but, following this, I'm asking whether tha $x$- and $y$-terms become 0.